# SVN Server And SVN Client : Update muliple server locations using svn client?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-server

I am a newbie to svn thing and know nothing about it, want some basic info or pointers about how to update multiple locations on server, here is my situation:
I have a web application and this web application runs on three different domains. These domains are created on same server. like http://www.domain-one/webapp, http://www.domain-two/webapp and http://www.domain-three/webapp. So i have setup the web app on three domains like the above urls and now problem is this when i update the code on my local system i have to update all these three locations and i update all these three locations manually via FTP. Is there any way where i can just update my code and do update automatically or just using any svn client to (Like tortoise svn) do udpate.(I use windows 7 and sever running linux with apache software).Can install any required software on server if needed. Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Preface**

Publishing (or delivery) your code to some point outside repository|working copy is not task of SVN (any SCM) per se - it's job of delivery tools, which can|must interact with VCS

**Face**

1. If webapp on every domain is Working Copy for the some tree of repository, you can `svn up` every WC in post-commit hook
2. If webapp doesn't related to SVN at all (some unversioned set of files), you can `svn export` into different targets three times.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. I got your point, now can you put some light on VCS? Don't know about it. Which is use to update non-repository code outside the svn. FYI every webapp is working copy of master code (its on my localhost system). Just want to update three working copies of code with master code whenever i changed or update the master code.

Comment: @Jay - "VCS" is synonym for SCM ("version control systems" vs "source control management"), SVN in part of this world. Deploy is different story (in common case). For your case - read about post-commit hooks in Subversion (case 1)

Answer (score 0):

I found the CI (continuous integration for php) tools work fine for me as they give me more control over many things like auto testing, debugging and auto upload files to server location.

I used couple of them and still learning. PHPCI and TeamCity from php strom. Hope this answer will give some pointers to others.